# ImportError: cannot import name 'Blog' from 'blog.models'

Tags: python, django, project, blogs, portfolio

Hi Can someone help me to sort out the below issue.
Actually, I have created a Port_Folio project and 2 apps with the name of Blog and portfolio.
When I import a blog in models it doesn't import and I am getting below error.

*****ImportError: cannot import name 'Blog' from 'blog.models'*****

**Actual code is:** [Import Blog Error-PyCharm Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32rRi.jpg)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog

admin.site.register(Blog)
```

**Error:**

```
 File "C:\Users\zeems\PycharmProjects\DjangoCourse\personal_portfolio-project\blog\admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Blog
ImportError: cannot import name 'Blog' from 'blog.models' (C:\Users\zeems\PycharmProjects\DjangoCourse\personal_portfolio-project\blog\models.py)
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that `blog/models.py` does not contain anything named `Blog`.  Can you show us that python module?

Comment: you should have to check if there is a Blog Model in blog/models.py. If you provide the models.py code. I can provide an updated code.

Comment: I think you might have a circular import

Comment: Show your blog model code.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your reply. I have already mentioned the code above its only 3 lines code. I am actually, taking the course from Udemy instructor name is Nick Walter I asked him as well and he did the same code as  did. Please have a look again the above code. *** from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog

admin.site.register(Blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look the actual code below.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Blog
admin.site.register(Blog)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.  I got it fixed. Actually, I forgot to change the name of 'Blog' while creating the class with the name of Blog. I kept it with the name of Project. Thanks once again.